# Is it normal to have many connections from my own server ip when I ran netstat command?

Tags: netstat

I would like to know if is it normal to have many connections from my own server ip when I ran:

```
netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | grep :80 | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head
```

The command explanation can be found here: http://www.mkyong.com/linux/list-all-ip-addresses-connected-to-your-server/ (I posted the link where I found the command after googling a while before I asked in here, and there are lots of explanation on that blog of what the command actually does. But somehow, I am lack of experience and need more info regarding this question. I kindly ask for your help and patience with me).

I got this:

```
223 MY OWN SERVER IP
  6 36.83.145.0
  6 141.0.11.183
  6 118.96.107.46
  5 114.121.128.224
  4 139.194.112.178
  4 125.162.210.152
  3 114.121.130.92
  2 82.145.211.30
  1 95.128.246.45
```

I thank you for your time to look and responses. Please, if you do not want to help me, kindly ignore this question, that would be more meaningful to me than giving unhelpful comments then making your own assumption, because it will lead to "mind-building" where other might think that I don't understand at all or have not googling around. Thanks a lot for your kindness!

Comment: Why don't you look at them to see what they are?

Comment: I tested your command, the top result in my case was not even an IP address. It was simply the empty string.

Comment: @MichaelHampton How do I look at them? The rest of the result output from top command seems pretty normal like NGINX, MYSQLD, PHP-FPM. Can someone just answer please is it normal to have your own server IP listed when running the command I gave above? Thank you for your kind answer, and please I am not an expert in this area, kindly your support.

Comment: First, you run `netstat -tn`. Second, it's a very bad idea to run commands you don't understand.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I appreciate you, but it would be more nice if you could be more helpful since this is the correct place to ask this question and I need help, that''s why I am here. Let me know if I am asking this answer in the wrong place then fine, I am sorry.

Comment: It completely depends on the applications you are running on your server.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen thanks a lot. I would vote up if I could.

Answer (score 3):

As already stated by Tero Kilkanen in its comment: "*...It completely depends on the applications you are running on your server...*".

Based on your very question, I assume that it's **not** easy, for you, to get an overall figure of your system so to decide if your 223 connections are "normal" or not.

In order to help you in deciding this, you need to understand **exactly** what such 223 (I mean the number; the very number you're basing your whole question) is telling.

What you've executed (...and cut-and-pasted in your question) is a chain of 8 commands, where the output of the n-th command is given as input to the n+1th, with the only exception of the first (that gets no input from nowhere) and the last (whose output is shown to you).

Let's check those commands one by one:

- **netstat -tn 2>/dev/null**: this will gets out the TCP connections currently registered within your system. Please note that:

  - *every* TCP connection will be matched, regardless of the state. This means that the output will contain, as an example, **ESTABLISHED** connection (hence, real, active, connections) as well as [**TIME_WAIT**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Protocol_operation) ones. In other words: not only real, established, connection will be shown. Discussing this in detail goes far beyond the scope of this answer. Please, document yourself at a reasonable minimum, before asking for details;
- **grep :80**: this will parse every single line coming from the previous output and filter only rows containing the text ":80". What normally this means is that **only connection related to HTTP** are selected. Please note that:

  - with such a "grep", **no distinction** is made regarding the TCP **source** or **destination** port. This means that lines filtered will be related to both **incoming** TCP/80 connections (the ones generally managed by your local web-server) and **outgoing** TCP/80 connections (the ones where your system **is a HTTP client**, for example when upgrading some packages/OS or when accessing some on-line services, RSS feeds, etc.);
- **awk '{print $5}'**: based on the lines filtered above, this will select the fifth column. Such column contain the **DESTINATION** IP address as well as the **DESTINATION** TCP port, in form like 1.2.3.4:5678. Please note that based on what stated above, destination TCP port will **not** necessarily be 80;
- **cut -d: -f1**: this will split the above couple (:) and will extract the first part (the IP address);
- **sort**: this will gets the output from the above command and produce a lexicographically ordered output;
- **uniq -c**: this will group the incoming lines (that are ordered) and count the number of occurences of each group, prepending such number (the count) to the value of each group;
- **sort -nr**: this will numerically order the values, based on the number that is supposed to be in the very beginning of each lines. Also the order is reversed (so from the highest, to the lowest);
- **head**: this will show (in output) only the first 10 rows of the input.

With all the above, it should be clear that: "when you launched above commands, in your TCP/stacks there were 223 sockets, in various states, including ESTABLISHED state, referring to **both** incoming and outgoing TCP connections with source port 80 or destination port 80."

Whether this is normal or not.... "*...completely depends on the applications you are running on your server...*".

As a final notes:

- please note that given the current trend regarding AJAX/asynchronous HTTP requests, it's perfectly common, for a **single** web page, to open --and keep opened-- several concurrent TCP/connections to the same target IP;
- a single outgoing (or incoming) [DOS attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) can produce a very high number of IP (including TCP or UDP) sockets.

---

P.S.: in one of your comment you wrote: "*Let me know if I am asking this answer in the wrong place then fine, I am sorry*". I really think that the place is right. But, as well, I think that you're mastering TCP/IP stack and general network and system administration at such a level that... I'm probably wasting my time writing this very answer :-)

Hope you'll appreciate this (...and start spending more time studying than asking this kind of questions on ServerFault)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I appreciated it very much! Yes, I am learning and practicing too. Do you recommend a great source for learning this?

Answer (score 1):

Are passed 2 years but I think this cmd could be more like this:

```
netstat -polenta | awk '{print $5}' | awk -F ":" '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head
```

Because it's more easy to understand, I've only add another awk that remove all the part after separator ":".
On this way you remove 2 cmds for using 1 ( cut -d: -f1 and grep :80 became awk -F ":" '{print $1}' ).

In the end the result is the same, i know, but I think you have at least one cmd less to write down on the terminal.